# PHP mail() function replacement?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

When I change providers I always have to make sendmail work and it's a real drag.

Are there any free providers I can use within my PHP code to send the same variables like keycodes for registration verification and stuff?

I tried looking on Google but I only found stuff that had form generators, which is not what I need.

Comment: So you want code to send e-mail or an e-mail provider? The title does not match the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) is one of the best mail solutions around for PHP. It's highly modular and can easily be configured to suit your needs. You could define [multiple transports](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) (in a config file for example) and use the one you need when you change providers.

Here is an example from the [docs](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html):

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
  ->setUsername('your username')
  ->setPassword('your password')
  ;

/*
You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:

// Sendmail
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

// Mail
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
*/

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Answer (score 6):

I use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) with great success.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an outgoing authenticated SMTP server so your not using the hosts one and don't have to change the details each time.

Take a look at [AuthSMTP](http://www.authsmtp.com/) (there are lots of other websites that provide this) and then use something like PHPMailer or Swift Mailer to send the email with authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a lot of ISPs block connections on port 25 (default smtp) to servers other than their own. Has to do with spam blocking etc.